# XML test messages validation against custom schema using Soap UI

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema, soapui

I have in house developed custom schemas and test messages that are needed to be validated against these schemas in SoapUI, all the research I have done so far hints at SoapUI only validating responses from web services against WSDLs.

I need to know if SoapUI is capable of performing a simple XML vs XSD validation, if yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

SoapUi is not the proper tool to perform these tasks. SoapUi can validate request and response xml but it uses the wsdl that was used to create the project. there is no option to just create a xml and assign a xml schema to it.

If you need a freeware xml schema creator / validator tool there several online options or you can download. you can use for instance Eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for yor answer although the link provided helps in understanding how to validate xml, but the xml is validated against the wsdl and not the schemas like I have mentioned in my question. Also, I have been directed to do it SOAPUI

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. SoapUI cannot perform the task you are requesting. Only if you use the xsd in a request or response that is described into a wsdl then you can validate the xml content. I've added the link as an alternative for you to look at other products. You can also use notepad++ with the xml tools plugin.

Comment: I understood SoapUI does not provide this functionality and I have to generate a WSDL to validate. Thanks